# Selenium: ExpectedConditions.UrlContains - possible bug?

Tags: c#, selenium

I am using the built-in function called `ExpectedConditions.UrlContains`. This function takes one parameter, a `string`. In some cases, the condition fails even though the URL is correct. Could this be a bug?

The code itself is pretty straight forward:

```
public static class SeleniumExtensionMethods
{
  public static WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(SeleniumInfo.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
  public static void WaitUntilUrlContains(this IWebDriver driver, String value)
    {
        try
        {
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.UrlContains(value));
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
}

 class HomePage : Page
{
  public void Login()
    {
      //Here is some code to log in ...
      //Here a redirect to a different page occurs ...
      String browserTitle = SeleniumInfo.Driver.Title; // returns "Index"
      SeleniumInfo.Driver.WaitUntilUrlContains("Index"); // returns the exception
    }
}
```

Exception message:

> A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to
>   the remote WebDriver server for URL
>   http://localhost:57623/session/69b23c4b9ca646f24b3312fcce02b3d6/url.
>   The status of the exception was ConnectFailure, and the message was:
>   Unable to connect to the remote server

As a last note, this exception never seems to other occurs in any of the other methods in my code, except for this one method where it occurs *occasionally*.

Why does it occur? How can it be fixed? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Try to set the timeouts of the driver to longer periods or try with different browser/driver.

Comment: a) The timeout is set to 20 seconds which is long enough. After this time, the page is definitely loaded, as well as the JavaScript. I can see with my own eyes that the page is loaded and the Url contains "Index", still it gives an exception, so making the timeout bigger isn't an option, sorry. Also, I use ChromeDriver only.

Comment: Maybe case sensitivity issue ? actual URL contains "index" but you are waiting for "Index".

Comment: Did you find the root cause of this issue?

Comment: I don't remember (it's 2 years ago lol). Are you having the same issue?